# Hold Alt to change keyboard layout in Windows temporarily

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I use OSX most of the day, but recently built a new desktop PC and started using Windows 10 as well. On my Mac, when I hold the Alt key, the keyboard uses the English keyboard layout, but only as long as I hold it down. This way I can quickly type characters that are not available that easily on my native (Czech) keyboard, and return to native without additional key press.

On Windows, there are alternative shortcuts to type the different characters (for example Alt+V to type @). Is there a way to make my Windows work like macOS?

**To clarify, I am not asking how to switch layout with shortcut press.** **I´d like to be able to write with different layout while I hold down certain key (like Alt).** After releasing it, it goes automaticaly back to my language.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/991729/23133

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I am not asking how to switch languages using keyboard shortcut. I wanted to know if I can switch it when holding particular key down (Alt) and automatically return to default after releasing it.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11, I just now used the "Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) Version 1.4" to make this happen. (In my case, holding down the right Alt-Key to be able to type the German special characters on an otherwise US keyboard layout.)

I followed the detailed instructions in answer to make that work: https://superuser.com/a/756357/313870

(I'm not copying their instructions here. Go to that answer and upvote it, they deserve the credit.)